# AS3 - Define shared object size

Tags: actionscript-3, cookies, shared-objects

I want to let the user save some bigger data in a **shared object** by choice. Is it possible to define the size the user needs to allow? 
I'ld like to set the minimum to at least 10 MB to have some extra space for future usage.

I'm talking about this permission window:

> http://www.flexdevelopers.com/b/uploaded_images/permission-773954.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [SharedObject.flush()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29) takes a `minDiskSpace:int` parameter.

Comment: If I ask for 10 MB the permission dialog shows "...up to unlimited". Is this normal? My code: mySo.flush(10485760)